# Managed package

Tags: managed-package

Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00N1t00000xxxx, field=Description, state=installed: newValue='null', oldValue='XXXXXXXX'

I got this error when I do validation via ant tool. This is because of latest managed package version has description field value and old one doesn't. So I have added description as in latest version to my file(file given for validation) after that I got below error,

Cannot modify managed object: entity=NamedFilter, component=null, state=MANAGED_INSTALLED - filters

Comment: Do you have reference to the managed object and/or field in your custom metadata? If so, I recommend you exclude the object and/or field from your package xml as the owner of the managed package can update attributes at any time.

Answer (score 0):

We will not be able to modify the managed package Objects/metadata.So,if you would like to update the description value which is available on the latest version then please upgrade the package in the destination org to the latest version to fix the issue.

Thank you!